# How to show & hide check boxes

Tags: sharepoint-designer

is was wondering how hard would it be to add in condition into share point new items form?
what i mean is; if a user selects a check box i want this to gray out other fields with the form... I know how to make this happen in.net but I am new to sharepoint designer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using InfoPath Form and Rules.
Here is a link to get you started using InfoPath:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg180738.aspx

And then you can use Rules in InfoPath to show and hide fields, here are some links that can help.
http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/customizing-sharepoint-2010-list-forms-infopath-2010
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKYBkr1a4sA
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/405406/SharePoint-2010-InfoPath-Forms-and-Rules

Let me know, if you would like a sample form?

Happy SharePointing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with infopath, but I would like to recommend you to use Forms Designer tool: http://spform.com. It has JS-framework to make forms dynamic.